# If you had a large group of people what would be the fastest way for the people to count themselves?

Tags: geometry, algorithms, arithmetic

(I realize this has a computer-sciency feel but I am pretty sure this is more about math than it is about computers. Maybe it is about information or game theory?)

I assume that there would be some partitioning and each group could count themselves in parallel with other groups and then perhaps pass the count along when done. You can eyeball the crowd but there is no explicit information at all.

What's more, the crowd in not in an enclosed area where by roughly calculating the area that the crowd packs and how much space each person occupies you could get an estimate quickly. On the other hand, the group could agree to crowd together.

The group could line up and count off and that would be probably pretty accurate; perhaps the line could try to do this in parallel by partitioning the line.

But all these shufflings and groupings would take time in themselves.

I think trying to form a square or rectangle might be the fastest way to get a count that is within 10% or so of the true number.

Importantly, there is no vantage point from which any member of the crowd is allowed to look and use techniques as listed here: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crowd_counting#:~:text=The%20most%20common%20technique%20for,the%20number%20of%20sections%20occupied](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crowd_counting#:%7E:text=The%20most%20common%20technique%20for,the%20number%20of%20sections%20occupied).

It is a completely flat plane. Everyone is of the same height and you can't make a human pyramid, etc. to give you the vantage point. Only the people at the edges know they are at the edges but they can of course share that information and everyone cooperates as much as possible.

You have to take into account that there are no leader chosen beforehand although they can elect leaders but if there are such leaders, this has to be conveyed.

Nobody has covid. There is no internecine fighting or violence of any kind but there can be confusion about, for example, who the leader or leaders are. People take up exactly the same amount of space. No fat or thin people -- and not that it matters but everyone is equally attractive, sort of average looking.

Comment: **Nobody has covid.** lmao!

Answer (score 1):

Use **Jacob's method**.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crowd_counting):

> [You] [divide] the area occupied by a crowd into sections, determining an average number of people in each section, and multiplying by the number of sections occupied.

Comment: as you were answering i was modifying the problem to avoid this boring answer. imagine how much harder the problem is when you a group of people all of the same height with almost everyone in surrounded by a sea of people.